# How to stop JPA entity manager from flushing before every select

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa

I am using JPA (with hibernate as the provider) in spring for a web-app.
I have a few methods that construct a complex object to be passed to the UI. As part of theses methods flow, a few `select` SQL statements are executed. The problem is that the entity manager flushes before each select, this action takes a lot of time and is hindering the performance. Is there a way to prevent the entity manager from flushing before each select? (I don't care for stale data in the select selects above)

Thank you.

Here is my GenericDAO

```
@Repository
public abstract class GenericDAOWithJPA<T, ID extends Serializable> implements IGenericDAO<T, ID> {
    private static final int MAX_RETRIES = 3;
    private static final long WAIT_INTERVAL_MS = 1000;
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericDAOWithJPA.class);

    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericDAOWithJPA() {
            this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }


    @Override
    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT)
    }


    @Override
    public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
        return persistentClass;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.legolas.dao.IGenericDAO#find(ID)
     */
    @Override
    public T find(ID id) {
        return entityManager.find(persistentClass, id);
    }


    @Override
    public T getReference(ID id) {
        return entityManager.getReference(persistentClass, id);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.legolas.dao.IGenericDAO#persist(T)
     */
    @Override
    public void persist(T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void persist(List<T> entityList) {
        for (T entity : entityList) {
            persist(entity);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public T merge(T entity) {
        return entityManager.merge(entity);
    }


    @Override
    public void remove(T entity) {
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }


    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("Select t from " + persistentClass.getSimpleName() + " t").getResultList();
    }


    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findInRange(int firstResult, int maxResults) {
        return entityManager.createQuery("Select t from " + persistentClass.getSimpleName() + " t").setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(maxResults).getResultList();
    }


    @Override
    public long count() {
        return (Long) entityManager.createQuery("Select count(t) from " + persistentClass.getSimpleName() + " t").getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        this.entityManager.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void refresh(T entity) {
        int retry = 0;
        RuntimeException lastException = null;
        do {
        try {
            this.entityManager.refresh(entity);
        } catch (OptimisticLockException e) {
            retry++;
            lastException = e;
            LOG.debug("OptimisticLockException retry {}", retry);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(WAIT_INTERVAL_MS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                retry = MAX_RETRIES;
            }
        }
        } while (lastException != null && retry < MAX_RETRIES);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code disables flush before queries (flush would occur only before commit):

```
em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
```

Comment: I used this option but for some reason Hibernate ignores this

Comment: ill post my generic dao from which all DAO inherit

Comment: @Noam: `EntityManager` injected with `@PersistenceContext` is not real `EntityManager`, it's a proxy that delegates calls to the real transaction-scoped `EntityManager`s. Therefore you need to call `setFlushMode()` in each transaction to configure real `EntityManager`s.

Answer (score 4):

You can also set your flush mode per query. It does not have to apply to the entire entity manager.

```
 TypedQuery<Person> people = ... ;
 people.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually run your own `SELECT` statements, how about asking the connection provider for a new connection? That way, Hibernate would be out of the picture for these queries.

Comment: I run the queries through the JPA entity manager, not directly against the DB.